# Ace Editor is causing infinite loop with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ace-editor

On my client side I have ace editor with onChange event handler which emits
the deltas to the server with socket.io and then from the server to all the users, thus every time a user receives new deltas ace will apply it and then emits 'change' event which will resend the same deltas to all users again.
Is there something I can do to prevent this like overriding applyDelta to prevent it emitting 'change' event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by adding a flag when applying deltas
like this

```
socket.on('newDelta', (delta) => {
    applyingChanges = true;
    aceDocument.applyDelta(delta);
    applyingChanges = false;
});

aceEditor.on('change', (delta) => {
    if(!applyingChanges)
         socket.emit('newChanges', delta);
});
```